# How to get all Taxonomy Term attached to Node?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

The Node has attached two terms.

[image]

`Term::load($node->get('field_posts_category')->target_id);` only returns first item. How to get all Taxonomy Term attached to Node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method `referencedEntities()` to get all terms:

```
$terms = $node->field_posts_category->referencedEntities();
```